# How do I find the difference between two values without knowing which is larger?

Tags: python, function, numbers, distance

I was wondering if there was a function built into Python that can determine the distance between two rational numbers but without me telling it which number is larger.
e.g.

```
>>>distance(6,3)
3
>>>distance(3,6)
3
```

Obviously I could write a simple definition to calculate which is larger and then just do a simple subtraction:

```
def distance(x, y):
    if x >= y:
        result = x - y
    else:
        result = y - x
    return result
```

but I'd rather not have to call a custom function like this.
From my limited experience I've often found Python has a built in function or a module that does exactly what you want and quicker than your code does it. Hopefully someone can tell me there is a built in function that can do this.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

`abs(x-y)` will do exactly what you're looking for:

```
In [1]: abs(1-2)
Out[1]: 1

In [2]: abs(2-1)
Out[2]: 1
```

Comment: But you'll face problem on sign while passing numbers dynamically. shared a working solution below. Please check

Answer (score 30):

Although **`abs(x - y)`** and equivalently **`abs(y - x)`** work, the following one-liners also work:

- **`math.dist((x,), (y,))`** ([available](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.dist) in Python ≥3.8)
- `math.fabs(x - y)`
- `max(x - y, y - x)`
- `-min(x - y, y - x)`
- `max(x, y) - min(x, y)`
- `(x - y) * math.copysign(1, x - y)`, or equivalently `(d := x - y) * math.copysign(1, d)` in Python ≥3.8
- `functools.reduce(operator.sub, sorted([x, y], reverse=True))`

All of these return the euclidean *distance(x, y)*.

Comment: It might be useful to explain why one might choose one solution over another.  From an outsider perspective, I would wonder "who cares?" if the shortest solution, `abs(x - y)` is correct.

Answer (score 9):

Just use `abs(x - y)`. This'll return the net difference between the two as a positive value, regardless of which value is larger.

Answer (score 8):

If you have an array, you can also use [`numpy.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html):

```
import numpy as np
a = [1,5,6,8]
np.diff(a)
Out: array([4, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 4):

So simple just use abs((a) - (b)).

will work seamless without any additional care in signs(positive , negative)

```
def get_distance(p1,p2):
     return abs((p1) - (p2))

get_distance(0,2)
2

get_distance(0,2)
2

get_distance(-2,0)
2

get_distance(2,-1)
3

get_distance(-2,-1)
1
```

Answer (score 2):

use this function.

its the same convention you wanted.
using the simple abs feature of python.

also - sometimes the answers are so simple we miss them, its okay :)

```
>>> def distance(x,y):
    return abs(x-y)
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not address the original question, but I thought I would expand on the answer zinturs gave. If you would like to determine the appropriately-signed distance between any two numbers, you could use a custom function like this:

```
import math

def distance(a, b):
    if (a == b):
        return 0
    elif (a < 0) and (b < 0) or (a > 0) and (b > 0):
        if (a < b):
            return (abs(abs(a) - abs(b)))
        else:
            return -(abs(abs(a) - abs(b)))
    else:
        return math.copysign((abs(a) + abs(b)),b)

print(distance(3,-5))  # -8

print(distance(-3,5))  #  8

print(distance(-3,-5)) #  2

print(distance(5,3))   # -2

print(distance(5,5))   #  0

print(distance(-5,3))  #  8

print(distance(5,-3))  # -8
```

Please share simpler or more pythonic approaches, if you have one.

Comment: same tests pass with :

    import math

    def distance(a, b):
        return (max(a, b) - min(a, b)) * (-1 if a > b else 1)

Comment: Surely what pansay has provided would be the best answer to this question?

Comment: The appropriately signed distance between two numbers (if there is such a thing) is `b-a`. I find the code needlessly complex and the problem it solves is not defined.

Comment: This is a ridiculous and pointless answer since `abs(a - b)` works for distance in all cases. It even returns negative distances sometimes which are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use the signed distance calculation snippet posted by phi (like I did) and your b might have value 0, you probably want to fix the code as described below:

```
import math

def distance(a, b):
    if (a == b):
        return 0
    elif (a < 0) and (b < 0) or (a > 0) and (b >= 0): # fix: b >= 0 to cover case b == 0
        if (a < b):
            return (abs(abs(a) - abs(b)))
        else:
            return -(abs(abs(a) - abs(b)))
    else:
        return math.copysign((abs(a) + abs(b)),b)
```

The original snippet does not work correctly regarding sign when a > 0 and b == 0.

Answer (score -1):

abs function is definitely not what you need as it is not calculating the distance. Try abs (-25+15) to see that it's not working. A distance between the numbers is 40 but the output will be 10. Because it's doing the math and then removing "minus" in front. I am using  this custom function:

```
def distance(a, b):
    if (a < 0) and (b < 0) or (a > 0) and (b > 0):
        return abs( abs(a) - abs(b) )
    if (a < 0) and (b > 0) or (a > 0) and (b < 0):
        return abs( abs(a) + abs(b) )
```

print distance(-25, -15)
print distance(25, -15)
print distance(-25, 15)
print distance(25, 15)

Comment: `abs(-25 - 15) = abs(15 - -25) = 40`. I don't know why you used `abs(-25 + 15)` -- that's an incorrect use of `abs` in this context. As for distance, `def distance(a, b): return abs(a - b)`.

Comment: The question was about the distance. For instance, the distance between -25 and -15 is not 40 it is 10.

Comment: And so what? Substituting `a` and `b` in `abs(a - b)` with -25 and -15 gives 10, not 40. In summary, `abs(a - b)` works for distance. It is noted in the first answer, and not in yours.

Answer (score -6):

You can try:
a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

[abs(x[1]-x[0]) for x in zip(a[1:],a[:-1])]