# How to find which value is closest to a number in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

Is there any method in python to find which of two values is closet a given number?

Say i have two values such as 1.5 and 5.5, and i want to find which of them is closest to 3. Not using Lists

Comment: [How do I find the difference between two values without knowing which is larger?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13602170)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `min` with a key function, the `abs` of their respective difference to the compare key:

```
min((1.5, 3.5), key=lambda x: abs(3-x))
# 3.5
```

Comment: numbers are not in a list, Without using list.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if there's a built-in function for doing this, but its so easy to do your self, for example:-

> Edit:-

Sorry i made some simple wrongs first because of i am using a mobile phone and i cant compile it but i fixed them:-

```
def closer(n1, n2, main):
    if(abs(main-n1)>abs(main-n2)):
        return n2
    else:
        return n1

print(closer(1.5, 5.5, 3))

#the result is 1.5
```