# Check diffrence Number is Less than 10 or Geater Than 10 in python

Tags: python

How to find if a number is less than or greater than 10 for difference.

> Example1: If a is 100 and b is 91. This is almost Matching.
>
> Example2: If a is 100 and b is 89. This is not at all Matching.

Below is the code and its working fine. Is there any other easiest or best way to achieve

```
a = 110
b = 100
c = a - b
d = a - 10
if a > b:
    if (a - b) <= 10:
        print "This is almost Matching"
    else:
        print "This is not at Matching"
else:
    if (b - a) <= 10:
        print "This is almost Matching"
    else:
        print "This is not at Matching"
```

Expected and actual are getting same

Comment: You can change your condition to if `abs(a -b) <= 10`, so no need to verify if `a > b`

Comment: You are looking for absolute value of the difference.

Comment: Yes absolute value difference

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602170/how-do-i-find-the-difference-between-two-values-without-knowing-which-is-larger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look for the absolute value of the difference `(a,b)`:

[The method `abs()` returns absolute value of x - the (positive) distance between x and zero.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_abs.htm)

```
a = 100
b = 110
print(abs(a - b))  # 10

if abs(a -b) <= 10:
    print("This is almost Matching")
else:
    print("This is not at Matching")
```

OUTPUT:

```
10
This is almost Matching
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `abs` to find the absolute difference:

```
a = 110
b = 100
c = abs(a-b)
if c<=10:
    print ("This is almost Matching")
else:
    print ("This is not at Matching")
```