# Why doesn't the range() function work when i use turtle module?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am following a paddles game tutorial and I am trying to get the ball to hit the paddles and change its trajectory.

I thought that it would be better if I used `range()` instead of the code shown in the tutorial but mine ends up not executed (the ball just goes through the paddles).

The code in the tutorial works perfectly.
The code used in the tutorial:

```
#Hit Paddles
if ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.xcor() < 350 and\
   ball.ycor() > paddle_b.ycor() - 40 and ball.ycor() < paddle_b.ycor() + 40:
    ball.setx(340)
    ball.dx *= -1
```

My code:

```
#Hit Paddles
if ball.xcor() in range(340, 350) and\
   ball.ycor() in range((paddle_b.ycor() - 40), (paddle_b.ycor() + 40)):
    ball.setx(340)
    ball.dx *= -1
```

The game was created using the turtle module, window `wd = 800`, window `height = 600`, paddles are `20 * 100`, and I placed them at `x = -350/350` and ball diameter is `20`.

Comment: FWIW, it's cleaner to do a chained [comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) for x: `340 < ball.xcor() < 350`, and [check the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13602170/4518341) for y: `abs(ball.ycor() - paddle_b.ycor()) < 40`

Comment: It is worse to use range(), because itonly works for integers and even then you have to compare 10 times instead of just 2 times

Answer (score 4):

The `range()` generates a serie of *integers*, not floats.

So `range(340, 350)` will give us `[340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349]`.

The turtle's coordinates will almost never be an exact integer, unless you program it to be that way.

If your turtle's `xcor()` coordinate is at, for example, `345.456`, the program will treat it as `not in range(340, 350)` (because it *is* not in the range).

So the float coordinates will likely not be in the `range()` you used.